# How do you loop a .replace over a column to change multiple strings to one string?

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, replace

I have a column in a dataframe that I am trying to fix all the spelling errors/input errors to the correct string (such a 'femake' to 'female). Is there any way to list all the spelling errors in one line of code to change them all to the correct variable. I have the following code. If a loop could work, how would I create a loop?

```
mh2014['Gender'] = mh2014['Gender'].replace('f' and 'woman' and 'femail' and 'cis-female/femme' and 'female (cis)' and 'cis female' and 'femake', 'female')
```

Comment: this question is a bit confusing to me - what are you trying to loop through *exactly*, and what is the loop specifically accomplishing? does the column only contain misspelled words, or is part of your question how to detect a misspelling?

Comment: Sorry I am just trying to change each occurrence of the certain strings listed to 'female' in an effort to clean the data.

Comment: do you have an excel/csv file or you just want to replace only the data shown in your example

Answer (score 4):

Assuming this is a Pandas DataFrame that you're using, you can simply re-assign the column to a list comprehension, in which you check for the misspellings as such:

```
misspellings = {'f', 'woman','femail','cis-female/femme','female (cis)','cis female','femake'}
mh2014['Gender'] = ["female" if entry in misspellings else entry for entry in mh2014['Gender']]
```

We use a set to speed up the lookup of misspellings because it has [O(1) average search time](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

If you want to add more misspellings to catch, modify the misspellings list, perhaps loading it from a file if the list becomes cumbersome to hard-code.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to loop over the strings you want to replace:

```
misspellings = ['f', 'woman', 'femail', 'cis-female/femme', 'female (cis)', 'cis female', 'femake']
for s in misspellings:
    mh2014['Gender'] = mh2014['Gender'].replace(s, 'female')
```

`and` doesn't do what you think it does. From the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-conditions):

> The Boolean operators `and` and `or` are so-called *short-circuit* operators: their arguments are evaluated from left to right, and evaluation stops as soon as the outcome is determined. For example, if `A` and `C` are true but `B` is false, `A and B and C` does not evaluate the expression `C`. When used as a general value and not as a Boolean, the return value of a short-circuit operator is the last evaluated argument.

For example:

```
>>> 'x' and 'y'  # 'x' is true so try next expression
'y'
>>> '' and 'y'  # '' is false so don't try next expression
''
>>> 'x' and ''  # Same as the first
''
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have used the word data frame in your question I expect it to be in pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('loation/to/myfile')
misspelled = set('f', 'woman', 'femail', 'cis-female/femme', 'female (cis)', 'cis female', 'femake')
df['Gender'] = df['Gender'].str.replace(misspelled, 'female')
```

Comment: I don't think OP wishes to actually include 'and' within the string to be replaced

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was probably in my sleep while using and. Corrected it